# JavaScript only allow user to click once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert this into vanilla JavaScript, to only allow the user to click once and prevent multiple clicks being recorded in Analytics.

**jQuery**

```
$('.test-link').one("click", function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});

<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a>
```

I Can't use jQuery, so any help would be great! thanks.

Comment: ('.test-link') will it be one or multiple elements ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In modern browsers, `addEventListener` accepts an `options` object which can contain a `once` property - if set to `true`, the listener will only trigger once, after which it will be removed automatically:

```js
document.querySelector('.test').addEventListener(
  'click',
  () => {
    console.log('listener running');
    return false;
  },
  { once: true }
);
```

```html
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a>
```

Without `once`, do it manually with `removeEventListener`:

```js
const test = document.querySelector('.test');
function listener() {
  console.log('listener running');
  test.removeEventListener('click', listener);
  return false;
}
test.addEventListener('click', listener);
```

```html
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a>
```

Comment: which version is better with once or remove event listener? Would this work for multiple elements? thanks :-)

Comment: When supporting modern browsers, either works fine, as you can see from the snippets. Old browsers don't support `once`, though. For multiple elements, you'll have to iterate over them with `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`

Comment: when i say there will be multiple elements, there will be lots of links with the same class that when this class is added they will only be able to click once. Sorry im new to JS, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Here is for multiple elements

> IE 9+

```js
var testEls = document.querySelectorAll('.test')

function clickHandler() {
    console.log('click');
    this.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
    return false;
}

Array.from(testEls).forEach(function(el) {
     el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
})
```

```html
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a><br>
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a><br>
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a><br>
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a>
```

Allowing different event types

```js
function oneEvent(selector, type, handler) {
  var elms = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var closure = handler
  
  var tmpFunc = function(handler) {
    closure()
    this.removeEventListener(type, tmpFunc)
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].addEventListener(type, tmpFunc)
  }

}

function clickFunction() { console.log('click') }

oneEvent('.test', 'click', clickFunction)
```

```html
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a><br>
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a><br>
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a><br>
<a class="test" data-label="track-this-link">Click</a>
```